# Java Class cast. Bug? Classloader?

Tags: java, spring, casting, weblogic

I have spring application in war file. I deploy it in differents environments and it runs good, but in one weblogic 12.1.3 server it fails.

I have a method like this:

```
public static Calendar getDate(Object obj) {
    if(object.getClass().getName().equals("oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP")) {
        try {
            return getCalendarFromSqlDate(((TIMESTAMP) object).timestampValue());
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("com.AWMonitor");
            logger.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And it fails giving me this error when i cast object to TIMESTAMP:

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP cannot be cast to oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I use ojdbc6.jar to use TIMESTAMP class, located in lib folder of my project and added to clashpath.

To use jdbc connections i use jndi datasource created in weblogic.

I did what Jon Skeet said. This is the result:

Object.toString(): ----

```
2015-11-10 07:20:08.904578
```

object getClassLoader ----

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@23137792
```

TIMESTAMP getClassLoader ----

```
weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@5a47f7ea finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@3b65acd6 annotation: AWMonitor@AWMonitor.war
```

Comment: Similar problems occured to me when I had more versions of the same library on classpath. However I used Tomcat, not Weblogic.

Comment: You are probably using 2 different versions of the oracle.sql package.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a classloader issue. I suggest you log `TIMESTAMP.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `object.getClass().getClassLoader()`. There's not a lot more we can say to help you at the moment...

Comment: that jar seems to be _provided_ so, check if you have the same oracle JDBC connector in the environments it works fine and weblogic as well (usually under lib folder in server home)

Comment: Thanks! I edit with more info about ClassLoader. It is posible that i have two versions of oracle.sql package? One in my project and one inside weblogic server installation?

Comment: Are both versions of oracle.sql package the same?